# Emacs script byte compile (with loaded libraries)

Tags: emacs, batch-file, compilation, elisp

The library suggests I use this in shell scripts to byte compile files:

```
emacs -batch -f batch-byte-compile files...
```

When I run this though, many don't compile, complaining because it hasn't loaded one library or another, I guess because it's starting up a new emacs instance without loading these libraries linked in my `.emacs`.

I keep Emacs running (24.0.50.1, cocoa emacs under Mac OS X, built from the git repo HEAD), with all these libraries loaded (or at least linked), so is it possible to batch compile files and have them find these libraries from this instance of Emacs?

Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a bunch of `eval-when-compile`s:

> eval-when-compile is a Lisp macro in
>   `byte-run.el'.
>
> (eval-when-compile &rest BODY)
>
> Like `progn`, but evaluates the body
>   at compile time if you're compiling.
>   Thus, the result of the body appears
>   to the compiler as a quoted constant.
>   In interpreted code, this is entirely
>   equivalent to `progn`.

Comment: Thanks. So that should sit in my `.emacs`, which will be read when  `batch-byte-compile` is run?